# Como criar um data.frame a partir de uma lista de vetores com diferentes comprimentos?

Tags: r, lista, dataframe

Eu tenho uma lista de vetores com comprimentos diferentes:

```
l<- list(a=c(1,2,4,3,2,5,6),b=c(3,2,3,2,1),c=c(32,3,2,6,7,6))
```

Eu gostaria de criar um data.frame a partir desta lista aonde as colunas seriam a,b e c e as linhas os valores dos vetores. Neste caso de vetores com diferentes comprimentos o ideal que a coluna fosse preenchida com valores NA. Eu costumava fazer, para vetores de mesmo comprimento, utilizando:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, l)
```

ou simplesmente:

```
as.data.frame(l)
```

Entretanto, me retorna apenas algumas linhas com base no vetor de menor comprimento da lista.

Comment: Pode mandar as informações de `sessionInfo()`? Arriscaria que tem relação com mudança nas versões do `R`

Comment: @TomásBarcellos, desculpe. Me expressei mal. Eu costumava fazer assim até que me deparei com listas com vetores com comprimentos diferentes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode aumentar o comprimento dos vetores menores da lista antes de unir as colunas:

```
cmax <- max(lengths(l))  # determina o maior comprimento

for (i in seq_along(l)) {
  length(l[[i]]) <- cmax
}

do.call(cbind.data.frame, l)
#>   a  b  c
#> 1 1  3 32
#> 2 2  2  3
#> 3 4  3  2
#> 4 3  2  6
#> 5 2  1  7
#> 6 5 NA  6
#> 7 6 NA NA
```

Comment: Nunca tinha visto alterar o `length` de um vetor. Muito legal.

Comment: Votei para cima mas em vez do `sapply` inicial, o `lengths(l)` dá os comprimentos dos vetores de uma lista.

Comment: Bem observado @rui-barradas. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta abordagem bem simples, obg! Vou adaptar para usar num pipe. Acabei tb descobrindo a função `plyr::ldply()` pra quem gosta do tidyverse.

Comment: @artur-indio Se chegou em uma outra solução, pode adicionar uma resposta pra sua própria pergunta. Pense que o SO não está só para ajudar quem posta a pergunta, mas outros que consultarem depois.

Comment: Ótimo! Irei fazer.